# How do i start mysql service in recovery mode from mounted hdd

Tags: mysql, linux, backup, server, database-administration

I had a server crash and mounted my disk to /mnt/

I made a backup of all datas for now just to be sure, but really need my mysql database with structure and datas.

I thought maybe its the easiest way to get mysql to run so i can make a database dump, Am i right?

Already tried to run /mnt/etc/init.d/mysql start

Or is there a way to copy all files and run the database locally on my pc?

Im stuck and really need some help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Got it to work!!!
The solution was to run these too:

```
mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount -t proc proc /mnt/proc
mount -t sysfs sys /mnt/sys
chroot /mnt
```